# How to make a formula work faster in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a new formula in a purchasing backlog file to compare the dates given by our forwarder and the dates in our system. However, sometimes the container names are different or have errors so I also need to check for characters in vlookup ("space" or "-" most of the time). I wonder the ways to make this formula work faster, like user defined function or maybe even a macro( this updates 3-4 times a week and there is already a macro to update the whole workbook)
Thanks a lot!

**Explanation**: basically we are taking the "abcd1234" container and checked it with forwarders excel file and compare the dates in both files. what makes this long is that sometimes there are mistakes file creating container like "abc 1234" or "abc1234-" etc.

Screenshot of formula is  [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuG7Q.jpg)

> =IF(AK2="";"NOT ON BOAT YET";IF(ISNUMBER(LEFT(AK2;1)*1);"NOT A CONTAINER";IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("
>   ";AK2));LEFT(AK2;FIND("
>   ";AK2)-1);IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("-";AK2));LEFT(AK2;FIND("-";AK2)-1);AK2));dates_in_DHL;9;0));IF(ISBLANK(AX2);"pas
>   dans planning";"There is a receipt transaction date, please
>   verify");IF(ISBLANK(AX2);IF(VLOOKUP(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("
>   ";AK2));LEFT(AK2;FIND("
>   ";AK2)-1);IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("-";AK2));LEFT(AK2;FIND("-";AK2)-1);AK2));planned_dates;10;0)=BZ2;"The
>   date is correct with planned column"&". The date of DHL is
>   "&DAY(VLOOKUP(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" ";AK2));LEFT(AK2;FIND("
>   ";AK2)-1);IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("-";AK2));LEFT(AK2;FIND("-";AK2)-1);AK2));planned_dates;10;0))&"-"&MONTH(VLOOKUP(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("
>   ";AK2));LEFT(AK2;FIND("
>   ";AK2)-1);IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("-";AK2));LEFT(AK2;FIND("-";AK2)-1);AK2));planned_dates;10;0))&"-"&YEAR(VLOOKUP(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("
>   ";AK2));LEFT(AK2;FIND("
>   ";AK2)-1);IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("-";AK2));LEFT(AK2;FIND("-";AK2)-1);AK2));planned_dates;10;0));IF(VLOOKUP(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("
>   ";AK2));LEFT(AK2;FIND("
>   ";AK2)-1);IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("-";AK2));LEFT(AK2;FIND("-";AK2)-1);AK2));planned_dates;10;0)>0;VLOOKUP(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("
>   ";AK2));LEFT(AK2;FIND("
>   ";AK2)-1);IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("-";AK2));LEFT(AK2;FIND("-";AK2)-1);AK2));planned_dates;10;0);IF(VLOOKUP(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("
>   ";AK2));LEFT(AK2;FIND("
>   ";AK2)-1);IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("-";AK2));LEFT(AK2;FIND("-";AK2)-1);AK2));dates_in_DHL;9;0)>BZ2;VLOOKUP(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("
>   ";AK2));LEFT(AK2;FIND("
>   ";AK2)-1);IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("-";AK2));LEFT(AK2;FIND("-";AK2)-1);AK2));dates_in_DHL;9;0);"The
>   date in DHL is earlier/same as the date in backlog"&". The date of DHL
>   is "&DAY(VLOOKUP(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" ";AK2));LEFT(AK2;FIND("
>   ";AK2)-1);IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("-";AK2));LEFT(AK2;FIND("-";AK2)-1);AK2));dates_in_DHL;9;0))&"-"&MONTH(VLOOKUP(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("
>   ";AK2));LEFT(AK2;FIND("
>   ";AK2)-1);IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("-";AK2));LEFT(AK2;FIND("-";AK2)-1);AK2));dates_in_DHL;9;0))&"-"&YEAR(VLOOKUP(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("
>   ";AK2));LEFT(AK2;FIND("
>   ";AK2)-1);IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("-";AK2));LEFT(AK2;FIND("-";AK2)-1);AK2));dates_in_DHL;9;0)))));"There
>   is a receipt transaction date, please verify"))))

Comment: I suggest swapping the VLOOKUPs for INDEX/MATCHs. They are much quicker, more robust and versatile. Can you post a screenshot of some sample data you are working with? It would help to understand exactly what you are trying to do. Id also suggest that formatting the formula would make it infinitely more readable.

Comment: I will indeed try to change VLOOKUPs, i also read it and should give it a shoot. Plus, i added my formula ss, it was my first post here so stil learning. Thanks for the help!